# VBA Script Idea for Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I was wondering if there was a way to 'view-protect' various sheets within a workbook with a pin number or password. I know there there is the protect workbook/sheet feature in Excel, but it doesn't view-protect, it just simply doesn't allow others to edit/change the sheet. Essentially, I would like to stop a sheet from being viewed within a workbook unless someone has the pin or password to it, and if I can do this, can I create multiple pins/passwords for multiple sheets.

The protect feature in Excel disables a user from selecting information in a worksheet, but doesn't stop them from viewing it. I have found some tutorials on YouTube regarding the VBA script that would be involved, but either the code isn't working very well or I'm not doing something right.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting up password using inputbox to hide/unhide excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72139992/setting-up-password-using-inputbox-to-hide-unhide-excel-sheet) (more specifically, the answer)

Comment: You can make sheets "very hidden" and could unhide them using code.  It would not be secure against anyone with even moderate Excel know-how though.